# MySQL If Else Statement Error

Tags: mysql, if-statement

For the life of me I cannot work out why this MySQL code doesn't work.

The aim is to check the credentials and if they exist, return the ID and if they don't then insert them and return the ID;

```
SET @Found = 0;

SELECT Id INTO @Found FROM Users WHERE Users.Username = "testAccount" AND Users.Email = "test@email.com";

IF @Found > 0 THEN
    SELECT @Found;
ELSE
    INSERT INTO Users VALUES (DEFAULT, "testAccount", "test@email.com");
    SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();
END IF;
```

Thank you for the help.

Comment: `SELECT Id INTO` instead of `SELECT Id INFO`

Comment: Sorry, that was just a typo when asking the question and wasn't the problem - thanks anyway!

Comment: And the error is....?

Answer (score 0):

The MySQL `if` statement only works in stored programs -- stored procedures, functions, and triggers.

That is what the first line of the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/if.html) means:

> The IF statement for stored programs implements a basic conditional construct.

So, your statement is syntactically invalid.

In addition, you have a syntax error in your `select`:

```
SELECT Id INFO @Found
FROM Users
WHERE Users.Username = "testAccount" AND Users.Email = "test@email.com";
```

What is being selected?  Should you have commas?  Or do you mean:

```
SELECT @Found := id
. . .
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, i'll have a look into procedures. Also the first select works and returns 0 if I select [at]Found afterwards so I assumed the syntax was correct for that part.

Comment: @SkelDave . . . Yes, `into` works for the `select` as well as `:=`, although I would normally use the `:=`.